# Saving data in matrix format in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, database, nosql

I am working with Cassandra and want to store data in matrix format. Currently, I am storing the values using Lists.
For example: I have created a table "matrix"

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (row_id int PRIMARY KEY, row_values list<int>);
```

And I entered some values in the table. (Note: the number of rows and columns can vary)

```
INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, row_values) values (1, [1,2,3,4,5,6,.......]);
```

Now I want to retrieve the 2nd element of the row_values, but with my method I am not able to retrieve the 2nd element of the list, however I can update and delete the element using below query:

```
UPDATE matrix SET row_values[1] = 50 where row_id =1;
```

Now my question is, whether it is possible to retrieve a specific element from list. If not then is there any other method which I can use to store data in matrix form and retrieve any element from the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Use `clustering column` instead of List and specify column index explicity as `column_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
row_id int,
column_id int,
value int,
PRIMARY KEY ( (row_id ), column_id ))
```

And now you can perform insert:

```
INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, column_id, value) VALUES (0, 0, 0);
```

Or insert multiple values by using batch statement:

```
BEGIN BATCH 
INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, column_id, value ) VALUES (1, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, column_id, value ) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, column_id, value ) VALUES (1, 2, 2);
...
APPLY BATCH;
```

All statements in this batch perform writes inside one partition and it will have good performance.

Retrieve value by `row_id` and `column_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE row_id = 1 and column_id=1;
```

or retrieve all columns by `row_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE row_id = 1;
```

But this solution has a poor side:  you should maintain sequence of `column_id` on application side.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why it has good performance? I will have to perform the operations very often, do you think there will be too much network overhead?

Comment: If all statements in a batch write inside one partition, coordinator node will communicate only with particular nodes for this partition. See documentation about batches: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html

Answer (score 1):

Not an Answer

There does not seem to any way to SELECT only one index value of list in cassandra

Not even in the map if you store index.

So the TABLE would be..

```
    CREATE TABLE matrix (row_id int PRIMARY KEY, row_values map<int, int>);
```

INSERT would be..

```
    INSERT INTO matrix (row_id, row_values) values (1, {0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,.......});
```

UPDATE would be..

```
    UPDATE matrix SET row_values[1] = 50 WHERE row_id = 1;
```

or

```
    UPDATE matrix SET row_values = row_values + {1:50} WHERE row_id = 1;
```

To DELETE a single map element would be..

```
    DELETE row_values[1] FROM matrix WHERE row_id = 1;
```

But you cannot SELECT single index value..

You have to store index as a column. Which does not seems clean but a very little we can do here.

This thing has been asked since long ago but nothing has been done I know of.

But if you will be querying this in some JAVA program, then you can fetch by using

```
    com.datastax.driver.core.Row.getMap()
```